# Controlling abbreviation of author names list using natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib, author-number

I am using the `natbib` package with the `aspr` style.

The command `\citep{key}` prints "(Smith et al., 2011)" if the number of authors is more than 3. How can I change it so that it uses the "et al." abbreviation if the number of names is greater than 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy the file `apsr.bst` to your working directory and rename it to, say, `myapsr.bst`. In the renamed copy, look for `FUNCTION {format.lab.names.abbr}` and here for the code line

```
    { numnames #3 >
```

Replace this line with

```
    { numnames #2 >
```

and compile your `.tex` file using `\bibliographystyle{myapsr}`.

Comment: I suspected that it was hard coded. Is there a biblatex style similar to `aspr`?

Comment: @egreg: At first sight, it's a fairly standard author-year-style.

Comment: It seems to have worked!